# Video Processing using Python and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to capture a video and convert into frames using python and openCV. I followed the steps that need to done to import openCV2 libraries for python in windows 8 which is as follows:

Download Python, Numpy, OpenCV from their official sites.

Extract OpenCV (will be extracted to a folder opencv)

Copy ..\opencv\build\python\x86\2.7\cv2.pyd

Paste it in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages

Open Python IDLE or terminal, and type

I have done the above steps to import opencv libraries into python.

But when I import CV2 libraries and try to capture a video, I was unable to generate frames using the function `cv.CaptureFromFile()` and accessing the frames using `cv.QueryFrame()` functions. I was unable to capture the frames. Please find the code below.

```
import sys
import os
import numpy as np
import PIL
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2.cv as cv

winname = "myWindow"
win = cv.NamedWindow(winname, cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

invideo = cv.CaptureFromFile("chayya1.avi")

totalNumberOfFrames = int(cv.GetCaptureProperty(invideo, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
framesprocessing = totalNumberOfFrames
print(totalNumberOfFrames)
while (True):
    im = cv.QueryFrame(invideo)
    cv.ShowImage(winname, im)
    if cv.WaitKey() == 27: # ASCII 27 is the ESC key
        break
del invideo
cv.DestroyWindow(winname)
```

The output is getting processed without any errors but the frames are not generating and even the print statement for frame count is also zero.

I just want to what is procedure for installing OpenCV for python in windows and accessing the frames of a video using the obove mentioned functions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried a different video or webcam? Also, do you have a current version of ffmpeg or gstreamer installed?

Comment: I have tried using webcam and it is working. When I give video file as input the function is not capturing the frames

Comment: seems that the video you want to parse cannot be decoded. I would try a different one and/or install/update ffmpeg

Comment: I have checked this with multiple videos. Could you please provide the process to install ffmpeg

Answer (score 1):

**Using opencv to read video files**

As mentioned in the tutorial [here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html#playing-video-from-file), the recommended approach now is to use `cv2` (not `cv` as you did) to read video files using, e.g.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("chayya1.avi")

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Python & OpenCV installation on windows**

For a simple solution to installing OpenCV's python bindings on windows you might want to try the [Python(xy) distribution](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/) which bundles a bunch of python modules [including opencv](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/wiki/StandardPlugins).

Python's opencv bindings are included with opencv, so if you didn't get any import errors then your opencv setup is likely to be correct.

*Alternative bindings*

If you don't like the native bindings, you could try using `pip` from the command line to install 3rd party bindings, though as berak pointed out this is not generally recommended;

```
pip install pyopencv
```

Pip itself can be installed as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows)

Comment: wait, pyopencv is not opencv's native python wrapper, but a 3rd party one ? (that would be a very bad idea )

Comment: Thanks for your comment @berak, updated post accordingly

Comment: You can also `pip install opencv-python` for official wrapper

Comment: @EranW - it seems not..."Unofficial pre-built OpenCV packages for Python."? Taken from the pypi page for `opencv-python`: https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/